# Sharepoint templates save/load content

Tags: richhtmlfield, template

I have a template with 3 RichHtmlFields. Each field requires a date range to specify a "go live" date for that content. Each field is also driven by geographical location.

The scenario is entering data in each field with different date ranges for each field, for different locations. Is there a way to create a template and save this data directly to sharepoint?

If not, is there a way to override what/where the data saved/loaded into the template/web page?

-TR

Update: It is a custom page layout that uses a custom ContentType deployed through VS2010. Essentially I am trying to save the content entered by the site admin in the RichHtmlField in my own database. Then allow the admin to change the content, and date range in the same RichHtmlField. The page will then display the content to the user for the current date.

The admin also selects a location, so depending on where the user is coming from, the content will be displayed according to the current date and location.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned "date-range" - why not creating a new Custom list (either backed up by a custom Content Type or if you use in a single list, then simply create appropriate columns on the list) having multiple "DateTime" fields (which allows also selecting just Date not only Date & Time) which enable users via a Calendar to select dates.

You could also use Column/List validation to create formulas which would check for valid range dates (e.g. end date not being set earlier than start date).

Finally, end-users would simply add new Items enabling you to record data in that particular custom list.

Hope I've got your scenario needs, otherwise please provide more details.